# How will I access MyAdmin database in onther computer using VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net, xampp, connection-string, lan

I have trouble accessing my database in **phpmyadmin** from another computer in my LAN
Every time I run my **vb.net application**, I get this error message:

```
Host 'GIAN-PC' is now allowed to connect to this MariaDB server (GIAN-PC is my computer name)
```

I think my connection string was wrong, this is my connecttion string:

```
server=30.1.1.11; user id=root; password =;database=systemdb;port=3306
```

Guys please help

Answer (score 0):

This is the connection string you have to use if you want to connect

```
Dim connection As New MySqlConnection("datasource=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=;database=s_t_d")
```

Of course you need to fill up with your details